# Unable to open PDF programmatically

Tags: c#, pdf, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling to open a PDF file inside of Unity. Currently, my application will open up the folder location instead of opening the actual PDF itself.

I've tried using both `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`and `Application.OpenURL` but they all act the same.

Right now, my code looks like:

```
Application.OpenURL(Application.dataPath + "/PDFS/" + pdfFile);
```

Now when I hard code in the file location like below, it opens up the PDF correctly:

```
Application.OpenURL("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Locator\\Assets\\PDFS\\foo.pdf");
```

Normally I'd leave it hard coded, but I need to allow one button to open any PDF. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Did you verify that both paths are the same?

Answer (score 0):

The string output of the two lines below are most likely not equal.

```
Application.OpenURL(Application.dataPath + "/PDFS/" + pdfFile);

Application.OpenURL("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Locator\\Assets\\PDFS\\foo.pdf");
```

Ensure the paths are the same and you should get the result you expect.

See the documentation for **Application.OpenURL** here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html

If you read to the bottom, you'll notice:

*"Note that the string returned on a PC will use a forward slash as a folder separator."*

This likely the reason why you're getting different results.

Also note that the value of Application.OpenURL changes based on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
string pdfURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath + "Documents/keyboard-shortcuts-Visual-Studio-Code.pdf";
```

it return below url and run in browser

http://localhost:1727/Documents/keyboard-shortcuts-Visual-Studio-Code.pdf

thanks
upendra